# NetBeans PHPUnit test generation ignoring @assert annotation

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I have an abstract class where source code looks like this:

```
/*
 * @assert (0) == NULL
 */
public static function factory($num) {
    if ($num==0)
        return NULL;

    //do some other stuff
}
```

If I delete the previously generated test file and use the "Create PHPUnit tests", it creates a new unit test file that doesn't seem to have taken the assert into account at all:

```
/**
 * @covers {className}::{origMethodName}
 * @todo Implement testFactory().
 */
public function testFactory() {
    // Remove the following lines when you implement this test.
    $this->markTestIncomplete(
            'This test has not been implemented yet.'
    );
}
```

I must be doing something silly, but I can't figure out what.  Is the failure to expand the class name and method name in the generated @covers annotation perhaps a clue?

I'm running NetBeans 7.0.1 on a Mac with PHP 5.3.6 and PHPUnit 3.6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All annotations must appear in DocBlock comments which start with `/**` and not `/*`. You're missing an asterisk.

```
/**
 * @assert (0) == NULL
 */
public static function factory($num) {
```